# How to fix AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'provider'?

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin

When I try to start this algorithm I get an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/trdina/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 145, in execute
    self.processAlgorithm(progress)
  File "C:/Users/trdina/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\algs\ftools\SumLines.py", line 85, in processAlgorithm
    spatialIndex = utils.createSpatialIndex(lineLayer)
  File "C:/Users/trdina/.qgis//python/plugins\sextante\algs\ftools\FToolsUtils.py", line 32, in createSpatialIndex
    provider = layer.provider()
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'provider'

I have no clue woh to solve this error. Any help is welcome.
Best regards

Comment: Should work in 1.8. Are you working with the current development version?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bug coming from the recent [QGIS Api changes](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/API_changes_for_version_20). Consider posting a detailed [bug-report](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues?set_filter=1) here. 
In the meantime try to use alternative tools like the Lines Properties function in SAGA (also accessible through sextante).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need sum of lines length in overlay polygon layer. So I think that SAGA - line properties doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: mmh and if you make a new attribute column called length and insert " $length " this will give you the length of all your lines. Now you simply have to sum them up. Alternatively join them first